# in ASP.NET VB, how can I maintain a fileupload backstepping a wizard?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have an asp:wizard with 7 steps - at one point the user is presented with an option to upload a file, or provide a link to an existing file on the internet.

At the end of the wizard, all of the information is presented for verification, and I have buttons for each section so as they can go back and edit something (if they spelled their name wrong).

In debugging I discovered that if I choose to upload a file, it will maintain until I get to the end of the form, but if I decide to go back and edit anything, the fileupload will dissappear.

Is there something Im missing to maintain that, or is it possible to? I'll post relavent code (there is alot, its a large form)

In the .aspx

```
                    <asp:WizardStep ID="uploadFileWiz" runat="server" Title="Upload File">
                        <!-- Step 4 - Upload a file -->
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="2" class="alignCenter">
                                    <%:uploadFileWiz.Title %>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="alignRight">
                                    File Location:
                                </td>
                                <td class="alignLeft">
                                    <asp:FileUpload ID="uploadFile" runat="server" CssClass="inputBox" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="alignRight">
                                    Is there a Password?
                                </td>
                                <td class="alignLeft">
                                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="uploadPasswordFlag" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">No</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </asp:WizardStep>

............................................
                    <asp:WizardStep ID="grandFinale" runat="server" Title="Lets Finish Up">
                        <!-- Step 7 - The final step. Verify information -->
                        <div class="margins">
                            <span class="label">
                                Lets Review:
                            </span>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="alignRight">
                                        Contact Name:
                                    </th>
                                    <td class="alignLeft">
                                        <%:contactName.Text%>
                                    </td>
                                    <th class="alignRight">
                                        Project Name:
                                    </th>
                                    <td class="alignLeft">
                                        <%:projectName.Text%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="alignRight">
                                        Contact Email:
                                    </th>
                                    <td class="alignLeft">
                                        <%:contactEmail.Text%>
                                    </td>
                                    <th class="alignRight">
                                        Project Location:
                                    </th>
                                    <td class="alignLeft">
                                        <%:projectLocation.Text%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="alignRight">
                                        Company:
                                    </th>
                                    <td class="alignLeft">
                                        <%:contactCompany.Text%>
                                    </td>
                                    <th class="alignRight">
                                        General Contractor:
                                    </th>
                                    <td class="alignLeft">
                                        <%:projectContractor.Text%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="alignRight">
                                        Phone Number:
                                    </th>
                                    <td class="alignLeft">
                                        <%:contactPhone.Text%>
                                    </td>
                                    <th class="alignRight">
                                        Bid Type:
                                    </th>
                                    <td class="alignLeft">
                                        <%:bidType.SelectedValue%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <!-- Buttons to go back and edit, if needed -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" class="alignCenter">
                                        <asp:Button ID="goToContactInfo" runat="server" Text="Edit Contact Information" CssClass="inputBox" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td colspan="2" class="alignCenter">
                                        <asp:Button ID="goToProjectInfo" runat="server" Text="Edit Project Information" CssClass="inputBox" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="alignRight">
                                        File:
                                    </th>
                                    <td class="alignLeft">
                                        <%:getFileInfo()%>
                                    </td>
                                    <th class="alignRight">
                                        Password:
                                    </th>
                                    <td class="alignLeft">
                                        <%:getPasswordInfo()%>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" class="alignCenter">
                                        <asp:Button ID="goToFileLink" runat="server" Text="Edit File Info" CssClass="inputBox" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td colspan="2" class="alignCenter">
                                        <asp:Button ID="goToPassword" runat="server" Text="Edit Password" CssClass="inputBox" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </asp:WizardStep>
```

In the codebehind...

```
'##### Edit button handlers
Protected Sub goToContactInfo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles goToContactInfo.Click
    rqBidWizard.ActiveStepIndex = 0
End Sub

Protected Sub goToProjectInfo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles goToProjectInfo.Click
    rqBidWizard.ActiveStepIndex = 1
End Sub

Protected Sub goToFileLink_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles goToFileLink.Click
    If selectFile.SelectedValue = "Attach File" Then
        rqBidWizard.ActiveStepIndex = 4
    Else
        rqBidWizard.ActiveStepIndex = 5
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub goToPassword_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles goToPassword.Click
    rqBidWizard.ActiveStepIndex = 6
End Sub

'##### String parsing functions
Protected Function getPasswordInfo() As String
    Dim isPassword As Boolean = False
    Dim thePassword As String = Nothing
    If uploadPasswordFlag.SelectedValue = "Yes" Or LinkPasswordFlag.SelectedValue = "Yes" Then
        isPassword = True
        thePassword = password1.Text
    End If
    If isPassword Then
        getPasswordInfo = "Yes: " & thePassword
    Else
        getPasswordInfo = "No"
    End If
End Function
Protected Function getFileInfo() As String
    Dim fileType As String = Nothing, fileName As String = Nothing, fileURL As String = Nothing
    Select Case selectFile.SelectedValue
        Case "Attach File"
            fileType = "Uploaded"
            If uploadFile.HasFile Then
                fileName = IO.Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.PostedFile.FileName)
            Else
                fileName = "None"
            End If
            fileURL = Nothing
        Case "Provide Link"
            fileType = "Link"
            fileName = Nothing
            fileURL = Trim(provideLink.Text)
    End Select
    getFileInfo = fileType & ": "
    If fileType = "Uploaded" Then
        getFileInfo = getFileInfo & fileName
    Else
        getFileInfo = getFileInfo & fileURL
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is that on a certain wizard step, the user uses the file upload control to pick a file, but that when they advance further and then return, the file upload control is empty ... I'm sorry to say that that's how the file upload control works.

Every time you change wizard steps, you're posting back and re-loading the page.  So the content the user provided is lost.  You might think that you could set the file name of the control programmatically on the server, but that doesn't work -- and rightly so, because it'd be a big security hole.  (How would you like to browse to a web page that could decide which of your files it wanted to upload?)

You're probably going to have to reorganize your wizard a little to work around this.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I figured maybe since it will maintain the file as you progress forward through the wizard, it should also as you move backward... I guess I will have to re-organize it :p